# R: gsub, pattern = vector and replacement = vector

Tags: r

As the title states, I am trying to use gsub where I use a vector for the "pattern" and "replacement". Currently, I have a code that looks like this:

```
  names(x1) <- gsub("2110027599", "Inv1", names(x1)) #x1 is a data frame
  names(x1) <- gsub("2110025622", "Inv2", names(x1))
  names(x1) <- gsub("2110028045", "Inv3", names(x1))
  names(x1) <- gsub("2110034716", "Inv4", names(x1))
  names(x1) <- gsub("2110069349", "Inv5", names(x1))
  names(x1) <- gsub("2110023264", "Inv6", names(x1))
```

What I hope to do is something like this:

```
  a <- c("2110027599","2110025622","2110028045","2110034716", "2110069349", "2110023264")
  b <- c("Inv1","Inv2","Inv3","Inv4","Inv5","Inv6")
  names(x1) <- gsub(a,b,names(x1))
```

I'm guessing there is an apply function somewhere that can do this, but I am not very sure which one to use!

EDIT: names(x1) looks like this (There are many more columns, but I'm leaving them out):

```
> names(x1)
  [1] "2110023264A.Ms.Amp"        "2110023264A.Ms.Vol"        "2110023264A.Ms.Watt"       "2110023264A1.Ms.Amp"      
  [5] "2110023264A2.Ms.Amp"       "2110023264A3.Ms.Amp"       "2110023264A4.Ms.Amp"       "2110023264A5.Ms.Amp"      
  [9] "2110023264B.Ms.Amp"        "2110023264B.Ms.Vol"        "2110023264B.Ms.Watt"       "2110023264B1.Ms.Amp"      
 [13] "2110023264Error"           "2110023264E-Total"         "2110023264GridMs.Hz"       "2110023264GridMs.PhV.phsA"
 [17] "2110023264GridMs.PhV.phsB" "2110023264GridMs.PhV.phsC" "2110023264GridMs.TotPFPrc" "2110023264Inv.TmpLimStt"  
 [21] "2110023264InvCtl.Stt"      "2110023264Mode"            "2110023264Mt.TotOpTmh"     "2110023264Mt.TotTmh"      
 [25] "2110023264Op.EvtCntUsr"    "2110023264Op.EvtNo"        "2110023264Op.GriSwStt"     "2110023264Op.TmsRmg"      
 [29] "2110023264Pac"             "2110023264PlntCtl.Stt"     "2110023264Serial Number"   "2110025622A.Ms.Amp"       
 [33] "2110025622A.Ms.Vol"        "2110025622A.Ms.Watt"       "2110025622A1.Ms.Amp"       "2110025622A2.Ms.Amp"      
 [37] "2110025622A3.Ms.Amp"       "2110025622A4.Ms.Amp"       "2110025622A5.Ms.Amp"       "2110025622B.Ms.Amp"       
 [41] "2110025622B.Ms.Vol"        "2110025622B.Ms.Watt"       "2110025622B1.Ms.Amp"       "2110025622Error"          
 [45] "2110025622E-Total"         "2110025622GridMs.Hz"       "2110025622GridMs.PhV.phsA" "2110025622GridMs.PhV.phsB"
```

What I hope to get is this:

```
> names(x1)
  [1] "Inv6A.Ms.Amp"        "Inv6A.Ms.Vol"        "Inv6A.Ms.Watt"       "Inv6A1.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6A2.Ms.Amp"      
  [6] "Inv6A3.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6A4.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6A5.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6B.Ms.Amp"        "Inv6B.Ms.Vol"       
 [11] "Inv6B.Ms.Watt"       "Inv6B1.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6Error"           "Inv6E-Total"         "Inv6GridMs.Hz"      
 [16] "Inv6GridMs.PhV.phsA" "Inv6GridMs.PhV.phsB" "Inv6GridMs.PhV.phsC" "Inv6GridMs.TotPFPrc" "Inv6Inv.TmpLimStt"  
 [21] "Inv6InvCtl.Stt"      "Inv6Mode"            "Inv6Mt.TotOpTmh"     "Inv6Mt.TotTmh"       "Inv6Op.EvtCntUsr"   
 [26] "Inv6Op.EvtNo"        "Inv6Op.GriSwStt"     "Inv6Op.TmsRmg"       "Inv6Pac"             "Inv6PlntCtl.Stt"    
 [31] "Inv6Serial Number"   "Inv2A.Ms.Amp"        "Inv2A.Ms.Vol"        "Inv2A.Ms.Watt"       "Inv2A1.Ms.Amp"      
 [36] "Inv2A2.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2A3.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2A4.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2A5.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2B.Ms.Amp"       
 [41] "Inv2B.Ms.Vol"        "Inv2B.Ms.Watt"       "Inv2B1.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2Error"           "Inv2E-Total"        
 [46] "Inv2GridMs.Hz"       "Inv2GridMs.PhV.phsA" "Inv2GridMs.PhV.phsB"
```

Comment: Can you give some example of what `names(x1)` looks like?

Comment: Please add the output of `names( x1 )` to the question...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Lot's of solutions already, here are one more:

**The qdap package:**

```
library(qdap)
names(x1) <- mgsub(a,b,names(x1))
```

Comment: mapply doesn't really work since gsub still doesn't work on vectors, but the qdap packages works flawlessly. As such, I'm choosing this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Beware: `qdap` has an enormous number of dependencies.

Comment: I'm quite aware since I wrote it. Secondly, there is no need for your warning.  It's open source and this info is spelled out plainly in the first page of the documentation.

Comment: That's like saying "there's no need to state the library used in this answer because you can always google the function". Sure, the warning might not be necessary, but it's still nice to know without doing further research.

Answer (score 33):

From `stringr` documentation of `str_replace_all`, "If you want to apply multiple patterns and replacements to the same string, pass a *named* version to pattern."

Thus using a, b, and names(x1) from above

```
stringr::str_replace_all(names(x1), setNames(b, a))
```

EDIT

`stringr::str_replace_all` calls `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex`, which can be used directly and is quite a bit quicker.

```
x <- names(x1)
pattern <- a
replace <- b

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  str  = stringr::str_replace_all(x, setNames(replace, pattern)),
  stri = stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(x, pattern, replace, vectorize_all = FALSE)
  )

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean  median   uq    max neval cld
  str 1022.1 1070.45 1286.547 1175.55 1309 2526.8   100   b
 stri  145.2  150.45  190.124  160.55  178  457.9   100  a
```

Comment: `str_replace_all` is close to the equivalent of the original poster's `gsub`. But `str_replace` might in some cases be preferred.

Answer (score 11):

#### New Answer

If we can make another assumption, the following should work. The assumption this time is that you are really interested in substituting the first 10 characters from each value in `names(x1)`.

Here, I've stored `names(x1)` as a character vector named "X1". The solution essentially uses `substr` to separate the values in X1 into 2 parts, `match` to figure out the correct replacement option, and `paste` to put everything back together.

```
a <- c("2110027599", "2110025622", "2110028045",
       "2110034716", "2110069349", "2110023264")
b <- c("Inv1","Inv2","Inv3","Inv4","Inv5","Inv6")

X1pre <- substr(X1, 1, 10)
X1post <- substr(X1, 11, max(nchar(X1)))

paste0(b[match(X1pre, a)], X1post)
#  [1] "Inv6A.Ms.Amp"        "Inv6A.Ms.Vol"        "Inv6A.Ms.Watt"      
#  [4] "Inv6A1.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6A2.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6A3.Ms.Amp"      
#  [7] "Inv6A4.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6A5.Ms.Amp"       "Inv6B.Ms.Amp"       
# [10] "Inv6B.Ms.Vol"        "Inv6B.Ms.Watt"       "Inv6B1.Ms.Amp"      
# [13] "Inv6Error"           "Inv6E-Total"         "Inv6GridMs.Hz"      
# [16] "Inv6GridMs.PhV.phsA" "Inv6GridMs.PhV.phsB" "Inv6GridMs.PhV.phsC"
# [19] "Inv6GridMs.TotPFPrc" "Inv6Inv.TmpLimStt"   "Inv6InvCtl.Stt"     
# [22] "Inv6Mode"            "Inv6Mt.TotOpTmh"     "Inv6Mt.TotTmh"      
# [25] "Inv6Op.EvtCntUsr"    "Inv6Op.EvtNo"        "Inv6Op.GriSwStt"    
# [28] "Inv6Op.TmsRmg"       "Inv6Pac"             "Inv6PlntCtl.Stt"    
# [31] "Inv6Serial Number"   "Inv2A.Ms.Amp"        "Inv2A.Ms.Vol"       
# [34] "Inv2A.Ms.Watt"       "Inv2A1.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2A2.Ms.Amp"      
# [37] "Inv2A3.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2A4.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2A5.Ms.Amp"      
# [40] "Inv2B.Ms.Amp"        "Inv2B.Ms.Vol"        "Inv2B.Ms.Watt"      
# [43] "Inv2B1.Ms.Amp"       "Inv2Error"           "Inv2E-Total"        
# [46] "Inv2GridMs.Hz"       "Inv2GridMs.PhV.phsA" "Inv2GridMs.PhV.phsB"
```

---

#### Old Answer

If we can assume that `names(x1)` is in the same order as the pattern and replacement and that it is basically a one-for-one replacement, you might be able to get away with just `sapply`.

Here's an example of that particular situation:

Imagine "names(x)" looks something like this:

```
X1 <- paste0("A2", a, sequence(length(a)))
X1
# [1] "A221100275991" "A221100256222" "A221100280453" 
# [4] "A221100347164" "A221100693495" "A221100232646"
```

Here's our `pattern` and `replacement` vectors:

```
a <- c("2110027599", "2110025622", "2110028045", 
       "2110034716", "2110069349", "2110023264")
b <- c("Inv1","Inv2","Inv3","Inv4","Inv5","Inv6")
```

This is how we might use `sapply` if these assumptions are valid.

```
sapply(seq_along(a), function(x) gsub(a[x], b[x], X1[x]))
# [1] "A2Inv11" "A2Inv22" "A2Inv33" "A2Inv44" "A2Inv55" "A2Inv66"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `mapply`.

```
names(x1) <- mapply(gsub, a, b, names(x1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Or, even easier, `str_replace` from `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
names(x1) <- str_replace(names(x1), a, b)
```

Comment: I posted this answer above already but here there's no need for `USE.NAMES = FALSE`

Comment: @TylerRinker Yep, you beat me to it.  `USE.NAMES = FALSE` gives a minor performance benefit that, for large datasets, may save you almost as much time as it took you to type the extra characters.

Comment: I tried str_replace_all from the stringr package, which should do as described. However, it gave me an error:

Error in check_pattern(pattern, string, replacement) : 
  Lengths of string and pattern not compatible

EDIT: I realised that str_replace_all requires names(x1) to be the same length as a and b, which is the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: @WetFeet Doesn't that mean that the `str_replace` solution is wrong? I think so but unsure since no one has raised that yet.

Comment: I don't think `mapply` works either, since it does not recursively apply gsub to names(x1)

Comment: Tested these and they both don't work.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do something similar but had to use base R. As long as your vectors are the same length, I think this will work

```
for (i in seq_along(a)){
  names(x1) <- gsub(a[i], b[i], names(x1))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Somehow `names<-` and `match` seems much more appropriate here...

```
names( x1 ) <- b[ match( names( x1 ) , a ) ]
```

But I am making the assumption that the elements of vector `a` are the actual `names` of your `data.frame`.

If `a` really is a pattern found *within* each of the `names` of `x1` then this `grepl` approach with `names<-` could be useful...

```
new <- sapply( a , grepl , x = names( x1 ) )
names( x1 ) <- b[ apply( new , 1 , which.max ) ]
```

Comment: Since the pattern is found within the names of x1, match returns NA values. grep1 doesn't really work too as it replaces the whole part of names rather than the part with the numbers (as in the edit)