# remove multiple patterns from text vector r

Tags: r, vector, gsub, mapply

I want to remove multiple patterns from multiple character vectors. Currently I am going:

```
a.vector <- gsub("@\\w+", "", a.vector)
a.vector <- gsub("http\\w+", "", a.vector)
a.vector <- gsub("[[:punct:]], "", a.vector)
```

etc etc.

This is painful. I was looking at this question & answer: [R: gsub, pattern = vector and replacement = vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector) but it's not solving the problem.

Neither the `mapply` nor the `mgsub` are working. I made these vectors

```
remove <- c("@\\w+", "http\\w+", "[[:punct:]]")
substitute <- c("")
```

Neither `mapply(gsub, remove, substitute, a.vector)` nor `mgsub(remove, substitute, a.vector) worked.`

`a.vector` looks like this:

```
[4951] "@karakamen: Suicide amongst successful men is becoming rampant. Kudos for staing the conversation. #mental"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[4952] "@stiphan: you are phenomenal.. #mental #Writing. httptxjwufmfg"
```

I want:

```
[4951] "Suicide amongst successful men is becoming rampant Kudos for staing the conversation #mental"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[4952] "you are phenomenal #mental #Writing"   `
```

Answer (score 14):

I know this answer is late on the scene but it stems from my dislike of having to manually list the removal patterns inside the `grep` functions (see other solutions here). My idea is to set the patterns beforehand, retain them as a character vector, then paste them (i.e. when "needed") using the `regex` seperator `"|"`:

```
library(stringr)

remove <- c("@\\w+", "http\\w+", "[[:punct:]]")

a.vector <- str_remove_all(a.vector, paste(remove, collapse = "|"))
```

Yes, this does effectively do the same as some of the other answers here, but I think my solution allows you to retain the original "character removal vector" `remove`.

Answer (score 5):

Try combining your subpatterns using `|`. For example

```
>s<-"@karakamen: Suicide amongst successful men is becoming rampant. Kudos for staing the conversation. #mental"
> gsub("@\\w+|http\\w+|[[:punct:]]", "", s)
[1] " Suicide amongst successful men is becoming rampant Kudos for staing the conversation #mental"
```

But this could become problematic if you have a large number of patterns, or if the result of applying one pattern creates matches to others.

Consider creating your `remove` vector as you suggested, then applying it in a loop

```
> s1 <- s
> remove<-c("@\\w+","http\\w+","[[:punct:]]")
> for (p in remove) s1 <- gsub(p, "", s1)
> s1
[1] " Suicide amongst successful men is becoming rampant Kudos for staing the conversation #mental"
```

This approach will need to be expanded to apply it to the entire table or vector, of course. But if you put it into a function which returns the final string, you should be able to pass that to one of the `apply` variants

Answer (score 1):

In case the multiple patterns that you are looking for are fixed and don't change from case-to-case, you can consider creating a concatenated regex that combines all of the patterns into one uber regex pattern.

For the example you provided, you can try:

```
removePat <- "(@\\w+)|(http\\w+)|([[:punct:]])"

a.vector <- gsub(removePat, "", a.vector)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a vector with statement "my final score" and I wanted to keep on the word final and remove the rest.  This what worked for me based on Marian suggestion:

str_remove_all("my final score", "my |score")

note:  "my final score" is just an example.  I was dealing with a vector.

Comment: This answer would benefit from formatting code as code and loading required libraries so the example can be reproduced.