# Looping over patterns list to remove them for a string column in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, stringr

I have a df with 2 columns where the second one represents strings that contains special characters and other characters I want to remove.

### The problem

I have written a `for` loop that works but only after being executed Three (03) times!

### Libraries & Data

```
library(tidyverse)
client_id <- 1:10 
client_name <- c("name5", "-name", "name--", "name-µ", "name²", "name31", "7name8", "name514", "²name8")
df <- data.frame(cbind(client_id, client_name))
```

### Patterns to be removed

```
patterns <- list("-", "--", "[:digit:]", "[:cntrl:]" , "µ" , "²" , "[:punct:]")
```

### What I have done

To remove the unwanted patterns in col 2 `client_names` I have written the following `for` loop:

```
for(ptrn in patterns) {
    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(client_name = str_remove(df$client_name, ptrn))

    print(ptrn) # progress
}
```

The above `for` loop removes all unwanted patterns, but only after being executed Three (03) times.

How can we fix that in order to remove all unwanted patterns since the first execution?

Should I nest the above `for` loop with another one in order to iterate over `client_names[i]`?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove multiple patterns from text vector r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036960/remove-multiple-patterns-from-text-vector-r). You do not need a loop to do this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421295/10264278 I think it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. The following works well: `df$client_name <- str_remove_all(df$client_name, paste(patterns, collapse = "|"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collapse the `patterns` in one regex pattern and use `str_remove_all` to remove all the occurrences of it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ptrn <- paste0(patterns, collapse = '|')

df <- df %>% mutate(client_name = str_remove_all(client_name, ptrn))
df

#  client_id client_name
#1         1        name
#2         2        name
#3         3        name
#4         4        name
#5         5        name
#6         6        name
#7         7        name
#8         8        name
#9         9        name
```

**data**

```
client_id <- 1:9 
client_name <- c("name5", "-name", "name--", "name-µ", "name²", "name31", "7name8", "name514", "²name8")
df <- data.frame(client_id, client_name)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak this works also well: `ptrn <- paste0(patterns, collapse = '|')
df <- df %>% mutate(client_name = str_remove_all(client_name, ptrn))`

Answer (score 3):

This is a more straightforward method:

Instead of making a list of all unwanted characters you can `str_extract` all and only the wanted ones, which, in your case, are the (Roman) alphabetic characters:

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(client_name = str_extract(client_name,"[A-Za-z]+"))
   client_id client_name
1          1        name
2          2        name
3          3        name
4          4        name
5          5        name
6          6        name
7          7        name
8          8        name
9          9        name
10        10        name
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, it works well too, but is some how less readable due to the used regular expression `"[A-Za-z]+"`

Comment: Well, if `[A-Za-z]+`is *less readable* then you have not seen many regex expressions yet ;)

Comment: I know I know 