# Which regular expression is more appropriate?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, string-substitution, gsubfn

I am trying to make models output prettier with pre-defined labels for my variables. I have a vector of variable names (a), a vector of labels (b) and model terms (c).

I have to match the vectors (a) and (c) and replace (a) by (b). I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403080/match-and-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-vector-of-text-without-looping-in-r) that introduced me to the function `gsubfn` from the package `library(gsubfn)`. The function match and replace multiple strings. Following their example, it did not work properly in my case:

```
library(gsubfn)

a <- c("ecog.ps", "resid.ds", "rx")
b <- c("ECOG-PS", "Residual Disease", "Treatment")
c <- c("ecog.psII", "rxt2", "ecog.psII:rxt2")

gsubfn("\\S+", setNames(as.list(b), a), c)
[1] "ecog.psII"      "rxt2"           "ecog.psII:rxt2"
```

If I use a specific pattern, then it works:

```
gsubfn("ecog.ps", setNames(as.list(b), a), c)
[1] "ECOG-PSII"      "rxt2"           "ECOG-PSII:rxt2"
```

So I guess my problem is the regular expression used as the argument pattern in the function `gsubfn`. I checked this [R-pub](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html), and Hadley's [book](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) for regular expressions. It seems that `\S+` is adequate. I tried other regular expressions without success:

```
gsubfn("[:graph:]", setNames(as.list(b), a), c)
[1] "ecog.psII"      "rxt2"           "ecog.psII:rxt2"

gsubfn("[:print:]", setNames(as.list(b), a), c)
[1] "ecog.psII"      "rxt2"           "ecog.psII:rxt2"
```

Which pattern should be used in the function `gsubfn` to match the vectors (a) and (c) and replace (a) by (b)?

Comment: No, `\S+` is not a good pattern, it matches more than you need. What are the exact *pattern* requirements? As an example, try `pat <- paste(a, collapse="|")` and then `gsubfn(pat, setNames(as.list(b), a), c)`.

Comment: I cannot provide a solution (no one can) until you clarify what contexts you need to find and replace in.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew, it worked perfectly! Thank you. I guess my understanding of character classes was not very clear. My context is that I am trying to make models output prettier with pre-defined labels for my variables. So I am extracting variable names (a) from a dataset, labels (b) from attributes of my dataset and model terms (c) from a coxph object using `broom::tidy` Sorry, it was not clear. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\S+` pattern fully matches `ecog.psII` and `ecog.psII:rxt2` and the list has no items with such names. You may create a pattern dynamically from the `a` vector and use it to find the matches you need.

Use

```
pat <- paste(a, collapse="|")
## Or, if there can be special chars that must be escaped (note . must also be escaped)
pat <- paste(gsub("([][/\\\\^$*+?.()|{}-])", "\\\\\\1", a), collapse="|")
## => ecog\.ps|resid\.ds|rx
```

and then use

```
gsubfn(pat, setNames(as.list(b), a), c)
```

If you do not escape special chars, you may overmatch (since `.` matches any char), match wrong strings (if there are quantifiers or other regex operators) or an error might occur (if there are chars like `(`, `)`, unpaired `[`, etc.).