# change numbers in string vector

Tags: r

I have a string Vector including numbers like this:

```
x <- c("abc122", "73dj", "lo7833ll")

x
[1] "abc122"   "73dj"     "lo7833ll"
```

I want to Change the numbers  of the x Vector and replace them with numbers I have stored in another Vector:

```
right_numbers <- c(500, 700, 23)
> right_numbers
[1] 500 700  23
```

How can I do this even if the numbers are in different positions in the string(some are at the beginning, some at the end..)?

This is how the x Vector should look like after the changes:

```
> x
[1] "abc500"   "700dj"     "lo23ll"
```

Comment: `sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {sub("[0-9]+", right_numbers[i], x[i])})`

Comment: Some related & possible helpful ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19424709/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29403080/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26171318/5325862)

Answer (score 2):

A vectorized solution with `stringr` -

```
str_replace(x, "[0-9]+", as.character(right_numbers))

[1] "abc500" "700dj"  "lo23ll"
```

Possibly a more efficient version with `stringi` package, thanks to @sindri_baldur -

```
stri_replace_first_regex(x, '[0-9]+', right_numbers)

[1] "abc500" "700dj"  "lo23ll"
```

Comment: Or straight with (more efficient) `stringi`: `stri_replace_first_regex(x, '[0-9]+', right_numbers)`

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thanks! I am not familiar with `stringi` package but I'll add this to the answer with your name.

Comment: `stringr` functions are shorter and simpler wrappers for  `stringi` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea,

```
mapply(function(i, y)gsub('[0-9]+', y, i), x, right_numbers)
#  abc122     73dj lo7833ll 
#"abc500"  "700dj" "lo23ll"
```

Comment: `sub()` should suffice