# How to get str_sub to accept output from str_locate_all when there are multiple replacements in a string and also assign replacements, vectorized

Tags: r, string, stringr, stringi, gsubfn

There are a lot of string replacement questions, but I could not find one that addressed this issue specifically.  I have a too long and slow if else for loop to solve this problem, but according to the str_sub [documentation](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_sub.html), the matrix output of str_locate_all should cleanly pass to str_sub once in matrix form.  I want to pass multiple matrices and assign multiple values simultaneously when a string has the pattern occurring more than once.  So something like below vectorized.

```
str_sub(text1, matrix_output) <- unlist(replacements)
```

Here is the text I am using for example:

```
text1 <- c("The current year is 2016 and the month is 05", "A following month is 08 with year = 2017", "There are other years.", "The final year will be 2053")
replacements <- list(r=c('2022','08'), r =c('09','2023'), r = '3167')
```

To get the matrix output you can run:

```
matrix_output <- str_locate_all(text1, pattern = '\\d{2,4}')
matrix_output <- matrix(as.matrix(matrix_output), ncol=2)
```

The desired output is:

```
[1] "The current year is 2022 and the month is 08"
[2] "A following month is 09 with year = 2023" 
[3] "There are other years." 
[4] "The final year will be 3167"
```

I am open to using other functions with str_locate_all's output, such as mgsub or gsubfn.

I tried using various combinations of str_replace_all, gsubfn,  and mgsub with str_locate_all to solve the problem, but all involved loops.

I also looked at gsubfn, and in particular this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403080/match-and-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-vector-of-text-without-looping-in-r) seems helpful.  But this post applies to the situation where you already have the substrings to be replaced, so it skips the step of getting the actual substrings using str_locate_all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `substring` assignment using the location matrix from 'str_locate_all'.

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
matrix_output <- str_locate_all(text1, pattern = '\\d{2,4}')
i1 <- lengths(matrix_output) > 0
names(replacements) <- which(i1)
for(i in which(i1)) stri_sub_all(text1[i],
      matrix_output[[i]]) <- replacements[[as.character(i)]]
```

-output

```
> text1
[1] "The current year is 2022 and the month is 08"
[2] "A following month is 09 with year = 2023"  
[3]  "There are other years."                      
[4] "The final year will be 3167"
```

---

The above solution can be vectorized further if it is a single string

```
text2 <- str_c(text1, collapse = ";")
 matrix_output <- str_locate_all(text2, "\\d{2,4}")[[1]]
stri_sub_all(text2, matrix_output) <- unlist(replacements)
text1 <- strsplit(text2, ";")[[1]]
```

-output

```
text1
[1] "The current year is 2022 and the month is 08" 
[2] "A following month is 09 with year = 2023"    
[3] "There are other years."                      
[4] "The final year will be 3167"
```

---

Or another option is to extract the digits and then use a named vector for replacement

```
library(gsubfn)
 nm1 <- setNames(unlist(replacements), unlist(str_extract_all(text1, "\\d{2,4}")))
gsubfn("\\d+", as.list(nm1), text1)
[1] "The current year is 2022 and the month is 08"
[2] "A following month is 09 with year = 2023"   
[3]  "There are other years."                      
[4] "The final year will be 3167"
```