# Removing text using R

Tags: r

I need help in removing text using R.

Below is the file that I have:

```
Name       Content
Re: fff    . Re: fff . I am a boy. She is girl...
GGOO       Laagg. jaja.
Re: QWE    . Re: QWE . I am pretty.
```

I would like to convert the file into the output below:

```
Name       Content
Re: fff    I am a boy. She is girl...
GGOO       Laagg. jaja.
Re: QWE    I am pretty.
```

Basically is to remove the text from the Content column if it matches with the text in the Name column using R.

I tried using gsub but it doesn't work. Below is the code I tried:

```
r <- gsub (df$Name, "", df$Content)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at this ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector

Comment: What do you want to do with the spaces and dots around your pattern?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I would like to remove them, but would like to keep the dots for the sentences after extracting the title in Content column

Comment: If any of the answers was useful for you, you should probably upvote/accept in order to provide some reward/feedback for the effort of all the people in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

```
d <-structure(list(Name = c("Re: fff", "GGOO", "Re: QWE"), 
                   Content = c(". Re: fff . I am a boy. She is girl...",
                               "Laagg. jaja.", ". Re: QWE . I am pretty.")),
              .Names = c("Name", "Content"), 
              row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
apply(d, 1, function(row) {
   reg <- row[1]
   reg <- paste("\\.[[:space:]]*", reg, 
                "[[:space::]*\\.[[:space::]]*", sep = "")
   gsub(reg, "", row[2])
})

# [1] "I am a boy. She is girl..." "Laagg. jaja."              
# [3] "I am pretty."
```

**Explanation**

`gsub` is not vectorized, that is it cannot deal with a vector appropriately. Hence, you have to loop over all entries of your data frame. I ammended the `regex` that it captures also the dot and the spaces.

Comment: This could be nice solution for the additional spaces but it won't work when there aren't any. For example, if you"ll replace `Name` at second row to `Laagg.`, it won't match.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
df$Result <- mapply(gsub, pattern = df$Name, replacement = "", x = df$Content)
```

---

The problem with `gsub` is that it only accepts one pattern. So to make it work with a particular, individual pattern for x '?mapply?` is the tool of choice in base R.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `stringi` package who has a vectorized and very efficient `stri_replace_first_fixed` function for that

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_first_fixed(df$Content, df$Name, "")
## [1] ".  . I am a boy. She is girl..." "Laagg. jaja."  ".  . I am pretty."
```

---

Edit: As per OPs comment, if there are possible spaces, you would need to build a regular expression (similar as in the other answer) and use `stri_replace_first_regex` instead

```
stri_replace_first_regex(df$Content, paste0("(\\.\\s+)?", df$Name, "(\\s+\\.\\s+)?"), "")
## [1] "I am a boy. She is girl..." "Laagg. jaja." "I am pretty."
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, using `Map` and `gsub`:

```
df$Content <- Map(gsub, df$Name, "", df$Content)
#     Name                         Content
#1 Re: fff .  . I am a boy. She is girl...
#2    GGOO                    Laagg. jaja.
#3 Re: QWE               .  . I am pretty.
```

Considering that the names seem to be always enclosed by a leading and ending period, separated with a single white space, and that the OP stated that these periods should be removed, the result could be improved with:

```
df$Content <- Map(gsub,paste(".", df$Name, "."),"", df$Content)
#     Name                     Content
#1 Re: fff  I am a boy. She is girl...
#2    GGOO                Laagg. jaja.
#3 Re: QWE                I am pretty.
```

However, this only works for patterns of the type ". name ."

Comment: `Map` is the same as `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`. It means that your solution will return a list column, which will be harder to use afterwards (just saying- no intention to fight over this :))

Comment: Yes, it returns a list. If necessary, the column can be treated with `unlist()` afterwards, or use `mapply` as you suggest. There are often similar solutions. This, as I said, is just one option. I don't claim that it's better, faster, or superior to other solutions in any way.

Comment: I think it's useful to know about different possibilities. For example, there are many similar ways to accomplish what `aggregate()` can do in some cases, and it may help to be aware of these different options.

Comment: Ok, This is will be my last comment on this. But if you look at the source code of `Map` it is just `mapply`- not something else. Your solution, although prints nice, gives a worse result though than just `mapply` because it returns a list. If the other guy would post a `Map` solution and you would post a `mapply` as an alternative, I could agree as it would have been an improvement, though IMO it's should be a comment as they are the same. This is nothing like comparing `aggregate` and `tapply` which are completely different

Comment: There are different opinions on this. Here's a quote from H. Wickham's book "Advanced R":
"You may be more familiar with mapply() than Map(). I prefer Map()
because:
• It’s equivalent to mapply with simplify = FALSE , which is almost always
what you want.
• Instead of using an anonymous function to provide constant inputs,
mapply has the MoreArgs argument that takes a list of extra arguments
that will be supplied, as is, to each call. This breaks R’s usual lazy
evaluation semantics, and is inconsistent with other functions.
In brief, mapply() adds more complication for little gain."(end quote)