# Variable substitution - R

Tags: r

Very simple question, but am struggling to find the solution.

Want to go from this:

```
a = c("the sky is color", "the color dog", "grass is color") 
b = c("blue","brown","green") 
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

To this:

```
a = c("the sky is color", "the color dog", "grass is color") 
b = c("blue","brown","green") 
c = c("the sky is blue", "the brown dog", "grass is green")
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Tried using gsub:

```
df$d <- gsub('color', df$b, df$a)
```

But received this error message:

```
argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Will the solution also work for integers?  Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine there's a neat vectorized solution, but you can do it with a simple `apply` statement.

```
a = c("the sky is color", "the color dog", "grass is color") 
b = c("blue","brown","green") 
df = data.frame(a,b) 

df$d <- apply(df,1,function(x){gsub('color', x[2], x[1])})


df$d
```

[1] "the sky is blue" "the brown dog"   "grass is green"

Comment: You could do something like `\`regmatches<-\`(df$a, gregexpr("color", df$a), as.list(df$b), invert=FALSE )` but the loop via `apply` is actually quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Most functions from the `stringi` package are vectorized, so you can just do

```
df$c <- stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(df$a, 'color', df$b)

df
##                  a     b               c
## 1 the sky is color  blue the sky is blue
## 2    the color dog brown   the brown dog
## 3   grass is color green  grass is green
```

Implement in dplyr or data.table if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mapply`

```
df$a <- mapply(sub, 'color', df$b, df$a)
df$a
#[1] "the sky is blue" "the brown dog"   "grass is green"
```

---

Or we can use `str_replace_all` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
df$a <- str_replace_all(df$a, 'color', df$b)
df$a
#[1] "the sky is blue" "the brown dog"   "grass is green"
```

Or using the `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(a = str_replace_all(a, 'color', b))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the `Vectorize` function that lets you specify some arguments to vectorize.  In this case, you want to vectorize the "replacement" argument and the string argument named "x":

```
(df$c <- Vectorize(gsub, c("replacement", "x"))("color", df$b, df$a, fixed = TRUE))
# [1] "the sky is blue" "the brown dog"   "grass is green"
```