# Can't seem to get vectorized gsub to work with library "qdap" and mgsub

Tags: r, regex, vectorization, qdap

I was looking at this question:

[R: gsub, pattern = vector and replacement = vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector)

I am trying a simple example and I can't get it to work.

```
testList <- c("apple", "orange", "banana1", "apple4", "orange 8", "banana 10")

repl <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")

pat <- paste0("^", repl, "[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*$")

result <- mgsub(pat, repl, testList)
```

Shouldn't this output:

```
"apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "orange", "banana"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `fixed = FALSE`, the default is `TRUE`, which replaces the pattern as is and doesn't use regex:

```
result <- mgsub(pat, repl, testList, fixed = FALSE)
result
# [1] "apple"  "orange" "banana" "apple"  "orange" "banana"
```