# Removing part of a string based on values from another data column

Tags: r

I have a dataset of schools, and I want to take out the prefix in front of the schools so it just has the school name (and sometimes a number). The prefix is is also listed in another column (tipo.organización), and so I want to take the value from tipo.organización and remove it from the name of the school (nombre.establecimiento).

I tried using gsub to remove part of the string from the name, but I couldn't just pass in the column name as a set of values to change. How could I get it to go through each value and compare to the tipo.organizacion column, and then delete what is not necessary?

```
data <- read.csv("...", header = TRUE)
data$nombre.establecimiento <- 
as.character(data$nombre.establecimiento)

#Remove Duplicates
new <- data[!duplicated(data$nombre.establecimiento),]

#tried to take out values from other column
new$nombre.establecimiento <- gsub(new$tipo.organización, '', 
new$nombre.establecimiento)
```

Thank you!!

[Link to dataset](https://catalogo.datos.gba.gob.ar/dataset/establecimientos-educativos/archivo/3951210e-7e0e-4fed-bbf1-0183e704c9ae)

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector) has a similar problem, and a lot of good answers.  The `stringr` approach would look something like this in your case:

```
new$nombre.establecimiento = str_replace_all(new$nombre.establecimiento,
                                             new$tipo.organización, '')
```

(I followed the link and got the raw dataset, and it's possible you may need to do some additional cleaning to get this to do what you want.  I'm seeing a lot of differences between the contents of `tipo.organización` and the beginning of `nombre.establecimiento`: accented/unaccented characters, extra words, etc.  You may already be doing this, of course!  A link to a cleaned-up dataset would be helpful for checking this piece of the problem.)