# Remove part of string in one column based on overlap with another column (context-dependent)

Tags: r, string, replace, tidyverse, stringr

I have the following data where everything is a string:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| "Do you like banana splits?" | "Do you like banana splits? Yes, I do" |
| "I am John" | "I am John I am Steve" |
| "I Voted for Biden" | "I Voted for Biden Why would you vote for Biden?" |
| "apple" | "apple" |

How can I remove the duplicated parts from Column B so that I'm left with the following:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| "Do you like banana splits?" | "Yes, I do" |
| "I am John" | "I am Steve" |
| "I Voted for Biden" | "Why would you vote for Biden?" |
| "apple" | "" |

I can't seem to find anything that doesn't just replace any overlapping words (e.g., turning Column B from "I am John I am Steve" to just "Steve"). I've tried using a for loop and gsub, but no changes seem to occur there either.

Comment: Please show us your code, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: You could try with stringr::str_replace(string = col_b, pattern = col_a, replacement = ""). Use stringr::str_squish() to remove extra spaces.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424709/r-gsub-pattern-vector-and-replacement-vector

Answer (score 0):

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77114980/remove-part-of-string-in-one-column-based-on-overlap-with-another-column-contex
tib <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~col_a, ~col_b,
  "Do you like banana splits?", "Do you like banana splits? Yes, I do",
  "I am John", "I am John I am Steve",
  "I Voted for Biden", "I Voted for Biden Why would you vote for Biden?",
  "apple", "apple"
)
tib
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col_a                      col_b                                          
#>   <chr>                      <chr>                                          
#> 1 Do you like banana splits? Do you like banana splits? Yes, I do           
#> 2 I am John                  I am John I am Steve                           
#> 3 I Voted for Biden          I Voted for Biden Why would you vote for Biden?
#> 4 apple                      apple

# with stringr::str_replace()
tib |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    esc_col_a = stringr::str_escape(col_a),
    new_col_b = stringr::str_squish(stringr::str_replace(
      string = col_b,
      pattern = esc_col_a,
      replacement = ""
    ))
  ) |>
  dplyr::select(-esc_col_a, -col_b)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col_a                      new_col_b                      
#>   <chr>                      <chr>                          
#> 1 Do you like banana splits? "Yes, I do"                    
#> 2 I am John                  "I am Steve"                   
#> 3 I Voted for Biden          "Why would you vote for Biden?"
#> 4 apple                      ""

# with stringr::str_remove()
tib |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    esc_col_a = stringr::str_escape(col_a),
    new_col_b = stringr::str_squish(stringr::str_remove(
      string = col_b,
      pattern = esc_col_a
    ))
  ) |>
  dplyr::select(-esc_col_a, -col_b)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col_a                      new_col_b                      
#>   <chr>                      <chr>                          
#> 1 Do you like banana splits? "Yes, I do"                    
#> 2 I am John                  "I am Steve"                   
#> 3 I Voted for Biden          "Why would you vote for Biden?"
#> 4 apple                      ""
```

Comment: you can also use `str_remove` :-)